# gmail-api Insufficient permission to delete mail

Tags: permissions, gmail-api

I am using gmail-api
I am getting insufficient permission for deleting mails.

I had the scope as { GmailScopes.GMAIL_LABELS,GmailScopes.GMAIL_INSERT,GmailScopes.GMAIL_MODIFY,GmailScopes.GMAIL_COMPOSE,GmailScopes.MAIL_GOOGLE_COM };

After seeing answer for same issue, i tried changing to

SCOPES = { GmailScopes.GMAIL_LABELS,GmailScopes.GMAIL_INSERT,GmailScopes.GMAIL_MODIFY,GmailScopes.GMAIL_COMPOSE,"https://mail.google.com/" };

but gets same issue

When i check for apps permissions at https://security.google.com/settings/security/permissions?pli=1

it says app doesnt have permission to delete mails. 
It has other permissions and other operations are working as expected.
Please help

Comment: You need to get a new `refresh_token`, since your last one has not run out yet. You can [force a prompt](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8942340/get-refresh-token-google-api) or delete the one you already have.

Comment: i dont use any access token in my code. i have registered my app with the package name and sha1

Comment: Have you tried or checked if you have the correct format of setting the scopes of the API? Kindly check this [Gmail API: Insufficient Permission](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30661489/gmail-api-insufficient-permission?rq=1) for formatting purpose? I hope this helps. Goodluck

Comment: yes, thats exactly what i tried by replacing GmailScopes.MAIL_GOOGLE_COM with "https://mail.google.com/"  .  but it didnt help .

Comment: can you get it to work here: https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/gmail/v1/gmail.users.messages.delete

Comment: No even that is not working. It ask me to authorize , there the scope selected is "https://mail.google.com/" . But i am getting invalid id error.I got message id from the mail option "show original" and the id for eg is Message-ID: <2.25696a43c4dd66f090f9@NY-WEB01> . I tried <2.25696a43c4dd66f090f9@NY-WEB01> and without <> also. But got response "code": 400,
  "message": "Invalid id value"

Comment: It s working . I got the ids using messages.list  api , and then tried. Then its successfully deleted . And the permission was only https://mail.google.com/

Comment: but for the same account it s not working when i try from my app