# Gmail API Signature Server Side

Tags: php, gmail, gmail-api, signature

I want to change all `signatures` from my Gmail domain. This domain has many accounts, and I need to change it from `server-side`.

I'm using `php`, and I started my project with:
php composer.phar require `google/apiclient:2.0`

I wrote one code, but when I try to update one email (like teste@mydomain.com), I receive:

```
{ "error": { "errors": [ { "domain": "global", "reason": "insufficientPermissions", "message": "Insufficient Permission" } ], "code": 403, "message": "Insufficient Permission" } }
```

My code `(using API client library)` is something like:

```
<?php

// initialize gmail
function getService() {
    try {
        include_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

        $client = new Google_Client();

        $credentials_file = __DIR__ . '/credentials/gmailAPI.json';

        // set the location manually. Credential server-side
        $client->setAuthConfig($credentials_file);

        $client->setApplicationName("GmailAPI");
        $client->setScopes(['https://apps-apis.google.com/a/feeds/emailsettings/2.0/']);

        $gmail = new Google_Service_Gmail($client);

        return $gmail;
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        throw new Exception($e->getMessage());
    }
}

function updateSignature(&$gmail) {
    try {
        // Start sendAs
        $signature = new Google_Service_Gmail_SendAs();
        // Configure Signature
        $signature->setSignature("Any HTML text here.");

        // Update account and print answer
        var_dump($gmail->users_settings_sendAs->update("someEmail@myDomain.com.br","someEmail@myDomain.com.br",$signature));
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        throw new Exception($e->getMessage());
    }

}

try {
    $gmail = getService();
    updateSignature($gmail);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}

?>
```

My credential file (gmailAPI.json) is one service account key, and I'm using Google for Work.

I created this credential using one administrator account from this domain.

`My credential file is:`

```
{
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": "myProjectId",
  "private_key_id": "myPrivateKeyid",
  "private_key": "myPrivateKey",
  "client_email": "gmailapi@projectid.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
  "client_id": "myId",
  "auth_uri": "url",
  "token_uri": "url",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "url",
  "client_x509_cert_url": "url"
}
```

**Edit 1**

I changed the scopes as instructed, and now my scopes are:

$client->setScopes(['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.settings.basic','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.settings.sharing']);

I also added permision on Google (/AdminHome?chromeless=1#OGX:ManageOauthClients) to my service account key.

I tried API explorer and it works. When i changed the scopes, the error changed to:

{ "error": { "errors": [ { "domain": "global", "reason": "failedPrecondition", "message": "Bad Request" } ], "code": 400, "message": "Bad Request" } }

I'm using this command:

var_dump($gmail->users_settings_sendAs->update("someEmail@myDomain.com.br","someEmail@myDomain.com.br",$signature));

I tried also

var_dump($gmail->users_settings_sendAs->get("someEmail@myDomain.com.br","someEmail@myDomain.com.br"));

But I received same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank You everyone.

I tried a lot of codes, and finally found one that works.

```
include_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
// credential file (service account)
$credentials_file = __DIR__ . '/credentials/gmailAPI.json';
putenv('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS='.$credentials_file);
// Initialize Google Client
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();
// scopes to change signature
$client->setScopes(['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.settings.basic','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.settings.sharing']);
// *important* -> Probably because delegated domain-wide access.
$client->setSubject("admEmailHere@test.com");
// Initialize Gmail
$gmail = new Google_Service_Gmail($client);
// set signature
$signature = new Google_Service_Gmail_SendAs();
$signature->setSignature("HTML code here.");
// update signature
$response = $gmail->users_settings_sendAs->update("admEmailHere@test.com","admEmailHere@test.com",$signature)->setSignature();
// get signature
$response = $gmail->users_settings_sendAs->get("admEmailHere@test.com","admEmailHere@test.com")->getSignature();
echo json_encode($response);
```

I commented all code, and I used https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/auth/service-accounts to create it.

Atention -> You need to give permission on Gmail, and create server key (with domain-wide access).

Comment: This worked perfectly for me except I had to remove `->setSignature()` from the end of `$response = $gmail->users_settings_sendAs->update("admEmailHere@test.com","admEmailHere@test.com",$signature)->setSignature();`

Answer (score 0):

I think your access token doesn't contain all `scopes` you want. First try in `API` explorer. Check what are the `scopes` API explorer request from you and then add those scopes to your code(place where you get permission).

https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer

hope this solves your problem

Comment: Thank you Januka,

I tried the API explorer and it works. I changed my scopes on my project (same as used in API explorer), and the error changed.

Comment: @Andre if my answer is useful upvote and mark it as right answer

Comment: Please remember to click "Mark as Answer" the responses that resolved your issue. This can be beneficial to other community members reading this thread.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the error **403 or Insufficient Permission** is returned when you have not requested the proper or complete scopes you need to access the API that you are trying to use. Here is the [list of scopes with description](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/auth/scopes) that you can use with Gmail API.

To know the scope that you are using, you can verify it with this:

https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?access_token=xxxxxx

> Note: You need to include all the scope that you are using and make
>   sure you enable all the API that you use in the Developer Console.
>   This [Delegating domain-wide authority to the service
>   account](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/auth/service-accounts#delegatingauthority)
>   might also help.

For more information, check these related SO questions:

- [Gmail API: Insufficient Permission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30661489/gmail-api-insufficient-permission)
- [How do I get around HttpError 403 Insufficient Permission?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32143126/how-do-i-get-around-httperror-403-insufficient-permission-gmail-api-python)

Comment: Thank you KENdi,

I changed my scopes and added permision to my key.
When I changed the scopes the error changed also.

Comment: For the error 400 of failedPrecondition, check these SO question [Gmail REST API : 400 Bad Request + Failed Precondition](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29327846/gmail-rest-api-400-bad-request-failed-precondition) and [Gmail API: 400 bad request when trying to send an email](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32591549/gmail-api-400-bad-request-when-trying-to-send-an-email-php-code) if it can help you.