# 403 error sending email with gmail API (python)

Tags: python, api, email, gmail, send

I'm trying to send an email using the Gmail API in python. I think I followed the relevant documentation and youtube vids.

I'm running into this error:

```
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: HttpError 403 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages/send?alt=json returned "Insufficient Permission"
```

Here is my script:

```
    #!/usr/bin/env python

    from googleapiclient.discovery import build
    from httplib2 import Http
    from oauth2client import file, client, tools
    from email.mime.text import MIMEText
    import base64
    import errors

    SCOPES = 'https://mail.google.com/'
    CLIENT_SECRET = 'client_secret.json'

    store = file.Storage('storage.json')
    credz = store.get()
    if not credz or credz.invalid:
        flags = tools.argparser.parse_args(args=[])
        flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets(CLIENT_SECRET, SCOPES)
        credz = tools.run_flow(flow, store, flags)

    GMAIL = build('gmail', 'v1', http=credz.authorize(Http()))

    def CreateMessage(sender, to, subject, message_text):
      """Create a message for an email.

      Args:
        sender: Email address of the sender.
        to: Email address of the receiver.
        subject: The subject of the email message.
        message_text: The text of the email message.

      Returns:
        An object containing a base64url encoded email object.
      """
      message = MIMEText(message_text)
      message['to'] = to
      message['from'] = sender
      message['subject'] = subject
      return {'raw': base64.urlsafe_b64encode(message.as_string())}

    def SendMessage(service, user_id, message):
      """Send an email message.

      Args:
        service: Authorized Gmail API service instance.
        user_id: User's email address. The special value "me"
        can be used to indicate the authenticated user.
        message: Message to be sent.

      Returns:
        Sent Message.
      """
      try:
        message = (service.users().messages().send(userId=user_id, body=message)
                   .execute())
        print 'Message Id: %s' % message['id']
        return message
      except errors.HttpError, error:
        print 'An error occurred: %s' % error

    message = CreateMessage('testemail@gmail.com', 'testemail@gmail.com', 'test_subject', 'foo')
    print message
    SendMessage(GMAIL, 'me', message)
```

I tried adding scopes, trying different emails, etc. I have authenticated by logging into my browser as well. (The testemail@gmail.com is a dummy email btw)

Answer (score 2):

Try deleting generated storage.json file and then try again afresh.

you might be trying this script with different scopes so "storage.json" might be having wrong details.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.

I solved it by running again the `quickstart.py` that provides google and change `SCOPE` so that google can give you all permissions you want. After that don't need to have `SCOPE` or `CLIENT_SECRET` on your new code to send a message, just `get_credentials()`, `CreateMessage()` and `SendMessage()` methods.